# Use operator<< overload from a class A within another class B to display content of class A object

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

My problem is as follows : I have two classes, one is Tree, and another one is Node. As you may have understand, Tree performs operations using Nodes objects.
As debug, I would like to use a Node << overload to display node content. For example :

```
class Tree {
(....)
    void InsertNode(Node *node){
      std::cout << node << std::endl; // I would like this to display for example node._data and other information
     }

}
```

What I've tried is first the "classical solution" I've always worked with, putting << overload outside of Node Class, but Tree still does not call this function.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Node &node)
    {
        os << "Node value here " << node.getData();
        return os;
    }
```

I have also tried to put it directly in Node class:

```
class Node 
{
     public: 
     (...)

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os)
    {
        os << "Node here " << getData();
        return os;
    }
}
```

But none of these solutions worked, the overload is not even called. Is it possible to perform such an action ? How can I do so ?

Thanks a lot by advance,

Comment: `std::cout << node << std::endl;` change it to `std::cout << *node << std::endl;` to call your `operator<<(std::ostream& os, Node &node)` overload

Comment: I've been turning around this but never used this with the good overload – many thanks !